# Make a link to login items?

Tags: login-items

In the course of installing some app, I came across the following.

**Put a link to it in your Login items to have it start up automatically when you login.**

How can I do that? How to make a link to login items with Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an item to your Login Items:

1. Open up the Accounts Preference Pane in System Preferences
2. Click on your Account and the click on the Login Items tab on the right hand side of the window.
3. Click the '+' button to navigate to the application or document you wish to open up on login.
4. If you wish you can check off the "Hide" checkbox to hide the application by default after it launches during login.

[image]

Comment: Drag-and-drop works too.